# Ruby on Rails: No method error in Rails 3.0.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.2.2, 3.0.10, 3.0.5, 3.0.3, 2.3.5, 2.1.0)
actionpack (3.2.2, 3.0.10, 3.0.5, 3.0.3, 3.0.0.beta3, 2.3.5, 2.1.0)
activemodel (3.2.2, 3.0.10, 3.0.5, 3.0.3, 3.0.0.beta3)
activerecord (3.0.10)
activeresource (3.2.2, 3.0.10, 3.0.5, 3.0.3, 2.3.5, 2.1.0)
activesupport (3.2.2, 3.0.10, 3.0.5, 3.0.3, 3.0.0.beta3, 2.3.5, 2.1.0)
arel (3.0.2, 2.0.10, 2.0.6)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1, 2.1.2)
bson (1.1.5)
bson_ext (1.1.5)
builder (3.0.0, 2.1.2)
bundle (0.0.1)
bundler (1.1.3, 1.1.1, 1.1.0)
cancan (1.6.7, 1.4.1)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.3.1, 1.2.0)
devise (2.0.4, 1.5.3, 1.1.5)
erubis (2.7.0, 2.6.6)
execjs (1.3.0)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0, 0.5.0, 0.3.7)
journey (1.0.3)
jquery-rails (2.0.2, 2.0.1)
jquery_datepicker (0.3.4)
json (1.6.6, 1.6.5)
libv8 (3.3.10.4 x86-linux)
mail (2.4.4, 2.2.19, 2.2.12, 2.2.7)
memcache-client (1.8.5)
mime-types (1.18, 1.17.2, 1.16)
mongo (1.1.5)
mongoid (2.0.0.beta.20)
multi_json (1.2.0)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
nifty-generators (0.4.2)
orm_adapter (0.0.7)
polyglot (0.3.3, 0.3.1)
rack (1.4.1, 1.2.5, 1.2.1, 1.1.3, 1.0.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-mount (0.6.14, 0.6.13)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1, 0.5.7, 0.5.6)
rails (3.0.10)
railties (3.2.2, 3.0.10, 3.0.5, 3.0.3)
rake (0.9.2.2, 0.8.7)
rdoc (3.12)
rolify (3.1.0)
sass (3.1.15)
sass-rails (3.2.5)
sprockets (2.1.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.5)
therubyracer (0.9.10)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10, 1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.33, 0.3.32, 0.3.23)
uglifier (1.2.4)
warden (1.1.1, 1.0.3)
will_paginate (3.0.3, 3.0.pre2)
```

Above is the gem list ..

I am maintaining a basic todo which will have sub tasks defined within each task but the command `task=Todo.tasks.new` results in no method error

```
amrit@PC148881:~/mytodos$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.10)
1.9.2-p290 :001 > todo=todo.first
NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.first
    from (irb):1
    from /home/amrit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@1.9.2/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /home/amrit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@1.9.2/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/amrit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@1.9.2/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
1.9.2-p290 :002 > todo=Todo.first
 => #<Todo id: 1, name: "Office", description: "work to be completed at office", created_at: "2012-04-17 08:53:35", updated_at: "2012-04-17 08:53:35"> 
1.9.2-p290 :003 > task=Todo.tasks.new
NoMethodError: undefined method `tasks' for #<Class:0xae32588>
    from /home/amrit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@1.9.2/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/base.rb:1014:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):3
    from /home/amrit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@1.9.2/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /home/amrit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@1.9.2/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/amrit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@1.9.2/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
1.9.2-p290 :004 > ^C
1.9.2-p290 :004 > t=Task.new
 => #<Task id: nil, description: nil, due_date: nil, due_time: nil, completed: nil, todo_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
1.9.2-p290 :005 > t.description="meeting"
 => "meeting" 
1.9.2-p290 :006 > t.save
 => true 
1.9.2-p290 :007 > task=Todo.tasks.new
NoMethodError: undefined method `tasks' for #<Class:0xae32588>
    from /home/amrit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@1.9.2/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/base.rb:1014:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):7
    from /home/amrit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@1.9.2/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /home/amrit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@1.9.2/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/amrit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@1.9.2/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
1.9.2-p290 :008 >
```

Comment: try to put just the error msg.... make it **human** readable :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you !! I got the answer I was doing a mistake while creating the instance I was trying this : t=Todo.new t=Todo.tasks.new instead of : t=Todo.new x=t.tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably unintentionally calling `tasks` on the Class instead of the instance.  Try this instead:

```
task=todo.tasks.new
```

Comment: Thanks you !! I got the answer I was doing a mistake while creating the instance
I was trying this :
t=Todo.new
t=Todo.tasks.new

instead of :
t=Todo.new
x=t.tasks.new 

since i was trying to create tasks within my todo

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is a simple typo you are doing

`todo=todo.first` , But what is  second `todo` ? Because it seems like you haven't defined it; in your second example you do

```
todo=Todo.first
```

Check the second example you do with capital 'T', try correct that or you can try

```
todo = Todo.all.first
```

(Assuming you have a AR model called Todo)